# Graphics.DrawIcon ignore scale transforms?

Tags: c#, graphics

Here's my code.  It looks like `DrawIcon` ignores the scale transform, but not the translate transform.  Is there any particular reason for this or is it just a bug?

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Icon icon = SystemIcons.Warning;
    Image img = icon.ToBitmap();

    // DrawIcon ignores this transform, but not a translate transform
    e.Graphics.ScaleTransform(1.5f, 1.5f);

    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 60, 90, icon.Width, icon.Height);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Icon", this.Font, Brushes.Black, 100, 100);
    e.Graphics.DrawIcon(icon, 60, 90);

    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, 60, 190, img.Width, img.Height);
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Bitmap", this.Font, Brushes.Black, 100, 200);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 60, 190);
}
```

[image: NOT Scaled] [image: Scaled]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's an explanation for it.  GDI+ doesn't support drawing icons.  It has no icon support at all.  Instead, Graphics.DrawIcon() delegates to Icon.DrawIcon() which calls a Windows api function to draw the icon, DrawIconEx().  The code otherwise forgets to take a scaling factor into account.  Probably intentional because negative and mis-matched scaling factors can't work, DrawIconEx() doesn't support that.  You can use the DrawIcon(Icon, Rectangle) overload to correct this yourself.

Comment: I thought it might be something like that.  I just couldn't find it documented anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Icon files (typically) contain multiple versions of the same image with different sizes.  The .Net Icon class represents a single image from an icon file, not the whole icon file.  You choose the size you want when you create the Icon class instance.

Traditionally, icon files had only two sizes (16x16 and 32x32).  You'd choose the one you wanted and display it with no scaling.  More recent versions of Windows support larger icons, and support scaling for displaying older icons at larger sizes.

The DrawIcon* functions seem to be designed to follow this model.

- The DrawIcon(Icon, int, int) function does no scaling.
- The DrawIcon(Icon, Rectangle) function does support scaling (but does not respect the scaling transform, presumably because the intention is to scale the icon to an exact pixel size).
- The DrawIconUnstretched(Icon, Rectangle) function probably has a different name just because the parameters clash with one of the other DrawIcon overloads.